# Getting the number of google search hits with google api

Tags: api, jsoup, google-crawlers

I am trying to get the number of search results with a custum search engine. I tried the following code:

```
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String google = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={mykey}" +
                "&cx={mycxcode}&q=" +URLEncoder.encode(searchString, charset) +
                ")&fields=queries(request(totalResults)";
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
    String totalResultsElementText = Jsoup.connect(google).userAgent(userAgent).ignoreContentType(true).get().text();
```

For this code i get the following error message:
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL={myurl}

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The url you are creating has error. You should change parameter `fields` to

`&fields=queries/request(totalResults)`, because `request` is a field of `queries`, but not an array.

More about partial selectors can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/performance#partial).

```
String charset = "UTF-8";
String google = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={mykey}" +
                "&cx={mycxcode}&q=" +URLEncoder.encode(searchString, charset) +
                "&fields=queries/request(totalResults)";
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
String totalResultsElementText = Jsoup.connect(google).userAgent(userAgent).ignoreContentType(true).get().text();
```

Your result is in form of JSON so you can extract final value like that:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(totalResultsElementText);
        System.out.println(json.getJSONObject("queries").getJSONArray("request").getJSONObject(0).get("totalResults"));
```